# Compress characters aabbbcccc+++ to a@2b@3c@4+@3 in javascript

Tags: javascript

the above question is asked at an interview, the code must accept input like aabbbcccc+++ and should output a@2b@3c@4+@3 based on the number of strings occurrences.

Comment: start with a loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try regex method or you can use the snippet below

1. Basic loop

```js
function compress(str) {
  let newstr = "";
  let count = 1;
  let index = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) === str.charAt(i + 1)) {
      count += 1;
    } else {
      newstr += `${str.charAt(i)}@${count}`;
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  console.log(newstr);
}
compress("aaaabbbbbccccc++++");
```

2. Use the regex method using above snippet **https://stackoverflow.com/a/54326492/7444617**

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex and captured in replace function.

`(.)\1+` - Here `.` means match anything `\1+` this means match the same character match by `(.)` one or more time. Than in the callback function we are returning concatenation `first` and `length of match` and `@`

```js
let str = `aabbbcccc+++`

let op = str.replace(/(.)\1+/g, function(match,first){
  return first+'@'+match.length;
})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: how can we do it without using built-in methods? like replace etc

Comment: @JpG you can use any loop and keep a two variable one for the current character and another for count of consecutive numbers. and based on condition you can build the desired string. give it a try using loop if feel any problem comment again will add a solution.

Comment: below is the logic, please verify for correctness,                       function compress (str) {
let newstr = '';
let count = 1;
let index = 0

  for (let i=0; i<=str.length; i++){
   if (str.charAt(i) === str.charAt(i+1)) {
       count += 1;        
      } else {
      newstr+= count+ '@' + str.charAt(i);
      count = 1;
      }
  }
  console.log(newstr);
}
compress('aaaabbbbbccccc++++');